# Graphic in marker lost quality

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Hello in mobile app I'm using Google Maps with custom marker image.
To set up own image I use this code

```
        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.testgraphic)));
```

It display graphic but with lost quality, it is very blured. How to fix it? I tryed many resolutions.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this:

BitmapDescriptor icon = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable. testgraphic)

MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().position(latLng)
        .icon(icon);

Comment: it dont fix the problem with losing image quality

Comment: I'm using only vector graphics